Arcsine Cordic Implementation using a lookup table
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define constants
K = 0.6072529350088813  # K value for CORDIC
NUM_ITERATIONS = 10     # Number of iterations for CORDIC
bitw = 15

# Function to compute arcsine using CORDIC
def arcsin_cordic(angle_ratio):
    #angle_rad = angle_deg * (math.pi/180)   # Convert angle to radians
    x = K                                   # Initial value for x
    y = 0                         # Initial value for y
    z = 0                                   # Initial value for z (angle accumulator)
    inpLUK = np.zeros(bitw)
    for j in range(bitw):
        tmp = math.atan(2 ** -j) #* (180/math.pi) #* (1 << bitw)
        inpLUK[j] = tmp
    #inpLUK = [11548, 8192, 4836, 2555, 1297, 651, 326, 163, 81, 41, 20, 10, 5, 3, 1]

    # CORDIC iterations
    for i in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        if y < angle_ratio:
            d = 1
        else:
            d = -1

        x_new = x - d * y * 2**(-i)
        y = y + d * x * 2**(-i)
        z = z + d * inpLUK[i]
        x = x_new

    return y

angle_array = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.15)
for angle_ratio in angle_array:
    # Compute arcsine using CORDIC
    arcsin_value_cordic = arcsin_cordic(angle_ratio)

The above code is to implement the arcsin using the Cordic implementation. Currently using this logic i am getting an error of -33 degree when the input is -1. the output should be -90 but the output from my code is -56.44. I am uncertain where the issue lies.

Your only mistake in the overall calculation is that the result for arcsine is z, not y (return z then). Also, don't use -1 or 1 to test the result, those are obviously the worse approximations. For example  arcsin_cordic(-0.5) * 180/math.pi gets -29.92914520840484 which is pretty close to the correct -30; also, the plot (with a stepsize of 0.005 rather than 0.15) gets pretty close to this one for instance.
